# How can you sort a vector with different times in r?

Tags: r

I have a vector that includes specific times and I was wondering how can I sort it based on the hour from earliest to latest?

```
vect<-c("12:00:00","01:00:00","24:00:00")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `order` after converting to time class

```
library(lubridate)
vect[order(hms(vect))]
#[1] "01:00:00" "12:00:00" "24:00:00"
```

If it only needs to consider the 'hour', extract the `hour` and `order`

```
vect[order(hour(hms(vect)))]
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
vect[order(strptime(vect, format = "%H:%M:%S"))]
```